# How to get a type property through a matching property of it?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this class:

```
class AClass {
    var name = "Name"
    var value = 0

    static var A = AClass(name: "A", value: 1)
    static var B = AClass(name: "B", value: 2)
}
```

I have a function that returns the name of `A` and `B`, how do I get `A` and `B` as `AClass` instances WITH string `A` and `B`, like this?

```
func someMethod(name: String) -> AClass
// func("A")  will return A: AClass
```

**UPDATE:**

I have many type properties in my actual project, so I'm looking for a convenient way to get 'em all without having to create a value of each type property.

Comment: syntax is correct?

Comment: @Mr.UB yeah, you think something's wrong?

Comment: `class:AClass` should be `class AClass`, are you using swift 3?

Comment: @Mr.UB oh sorry, didn't see that, lol

Comment: did You implement Initializers function? You can get static var directly via Class, just use AClass.A or AClass.B

Comment: @ABáo in my project there is an initializer, but I don't think I need one in the example here. That is a way to do it, but I hope to find a easier way because there are many type properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
class AClass {
 var name = "Name"
 var value = 0

 static var dataDict = [String: AClass]()

 init(name: String) {
  self.name = name
 }


static func someMethod(name: String) -> AClass {
 if let obj = AClass.dataDict[name] {
  return obj
} else {
  AClass.dataDict[name] = AClass(name: name)
  return AClass.dataDict[name]!
}

}
```

}

Get object of AClass like:

```
let obj = AClass.someMethod(stringReturnValue) // AClass.someMethod("A")
```

// here if already AClass object exist with this key in  AClass.dataDict then it will return that object else created one and store it in  dataDict.

Comment: Yeah I think you get it, eventually I created a dictionary, similar to yours to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
class AClass {
    var name = "Name"
    var value = 0

    static var A = AClass(name: "A", value: 1)
    static var B = AClass(name: "B", value: 2)

    init(name:String, value:NSInteger){
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Get it like this:

```
let aObj = AClass.A
let bObj = AClass.B

print(aObj.name)
print(bObj.name)
```

Comment: Yeah this is a way to do it, but in face my class has many type properties, this is kind of tough to do.

Comment: @BrightFuture - Please add more details into your question like how many variable and other details.

Comment: I think I made you misunderstand the question :)

Comment: That means in my class there are instances `A ~ Z`, and I have to get them with string A, B, C, maybe I need something like a dictionary for it

Comment: Oh I understand. Let me think.

Comment: why do you need A to Z instances?  i got ur question but what's  the need to make several instances? @BrightFuture

Comment: @SahilBeri I need to let user select several instances of AClass, then use their values to do calculation

Comment: The syntax in which you are looking for the solution :`static let`, IMO, its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class AClass
{
    var name = "Name"
    var value = 0

    init(name : String, value : Int)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }

    static var A = AClass(name: "A", value: 1)
    static var B = AClass(name: "B", value: 2)
}
```

To get A and B as AClass instances use:

```
let objA = AClass.A
print(objA.name)
let objB = AClass.B
print(objB.name)
```

Comment: I think I made you misunderstand the question :)